# Heat Equation with Initial Data in $L^1.$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes, greens-function, parabolic-pde

In Friedman's book PDE’s of Parabolic Type, the Green function $G$ for the heat equation is said to satisfy
\begin{equation*}
G_t - \Delta G = 0
\end{equation*}
in $\Omega\times(0,T)$ and $G=0$ on $\partial\Omega\times(0,T)$, where $\Omega$ is a open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary.

Furthermore, it is stated that for a continuous function $f$ with compact support, i.e., $f\in C_c(\Omega)$ we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\rightarrow0} \int_\Omega G(x,y,t) f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y = f(x)
\end{equation}
for every $x\in \Omega$.

**Question 1.** Shouldn't it be enough for $f$ to be in $C(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ in order for the last property above to be true?

**Question 2** In papers they often state that for $f\in L^1(\Omega)$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\rightarrow0} \int_\Omega G(x,y,t) f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y = f(x)
\end{equation}
for a.e. $x\in \Omega$. How does one show this?

Comment: Using the density of $C_c(\Omega )$ in $C(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ and in $L^1(\Omega)
$, the smoothness of $G$ and Lebegue dominated theorem gives you the answer to both questions.